# Flutter web how to get image using camera and upload to firebase storage

Tags: camera, firebase-storage, flutter-web, image-upload

I want to know how to get image using camera (not gallery) in flutter web. Currently i am using `image_picker` package, but i cannot get image as File. That package return `NetworkImage`. Also I tried using `image_picker_web`. In that package i can get html.file, but i cannot get it using camera. Are there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's rock buddy....

Check these resources, it seems pretty same to your scenario;

1. https://github.com/flutter/photobooth
2. https://medium.com/flutter/how-its-made-i-o-photo-booth-3b8355d35883

try to gain knowledge and learn from these open source project. Reply back if this is helpful to sort out the problem or share with us how did you solved it.

Comment: Thank You for your comment. I found the answer. Instead of putFIle() in firebase_storage i used putData() and give it to Uint8List.